# convert PDF to HTML with pdf2htmlEX and kristin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf

pdf2htmlEX renders PDF files in HTML. It aims to provide an accurate rendering, while keeping optimized for Web display. After some demos I got convinced to use this:

[demo1](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/demo/geneve.html)

[demo2](http://coolwanglu.github.io/pdf2htmlEX/demo/issue65_en.html)

I could manage to install pdf2htmlEX and convert locally PDF to HTML, however I want to use it in my rails app. So, I found kristin gem, which makes exactly that.

My concern is that I'm lacking of some knowledge to make it work, basically how to use this gem. Here is a repo of [kristin](https://github.com/ricn/kristin), where in usage section is written what to do. Some basic question I'm concern of:

1. Where exactly I store **require 'kristin'**? Currently it's in application.rb
2. Kristin.convert('http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf', 'example.html'). Where do I store this line? I have tried in many ways but with no success.

I assume after this few steps I will get basic functionality of pdf2htmlEX in my app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

CloudConvert (https://cloudconvert.com/) is a free/cheap online service that uses the same `pdf2htmlEX` (C++) software as the `kristin` gem, but allows you to convert PDFs (or many other file types) to HTML (or others) via a very simple API instead of having to install `pdf2htmlEX` on your local machine/production server. The gem `cloudconvert-ruby` wraps the CloudConvert API, thus making it all very easy and Ruby-centric.

Be forewarned, the HTML document that `pdf2htmlEX` produces (whether inline or in separated files [images, CSS files, HTML, JS, etc.]) has an HTML/CSS structure that makes is all but impossible to edit without breaking the code.

Answer (score 0):

You may have already found a solution by now, but for posterity, you would `require 'kristin'` in whatever **.rb** file you needed to use it (although Bundler should be taking care of that for you if you added `gem 'kristin'` to your Gemfile). Then you can proceed to use the helper method `Kristin.convert(...)` wherever you need to.

Just realize that this is not a 'drop in' solution for your production environment. You would need to install pdf2htmlEX on the production machine as well (hence the comment in kristin's example: `# This requires that the pdf2htmlEX command is present in your PATH.`)
 For example, you wouldn't be able to do this on a managed PaaS like Heroku.

Hope this helps someone.